# Attribute Error while importing views in Urls.py in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, url, django-rest-framework, django-views

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response
from App.serializers import *
from App.models import *
from App.serializers import *


# Create your views here.
class ListUsers(APIView):
    """
    View to list all users in the system.

    * Requires token authentication.
    * Only admin users are able to access this view.
    """
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return a list of all users.
        """
        usernames = [user.username for user in User.objects.all()]
        return Response(usernames)
 
class CustomAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'user_id': user.pk,
            'email': user.email
        })

@api_view(['GET'])
def consol_overall_view(request):
    user = Users.objects.values('id','employee_name','billable_and_non_billable',)
    qs = conso_serializers(user, many= True)
    proj = Add_Job.objects.values('project','user','client')
    qs1 = timelog_serializers(proj, many= True)
    cli = Add_Timelog.objects.values('Date','Hours','project_id')
    qs2 = time_serializers(cli,many= True)
    return Response(qs.data+qs1.data+qs2.data,status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.urls import re_path
from django import views
from App.views import CustomAuthToken
from.router import router
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from App.views import consol_overall_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="social_app/index.html")), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include(router.urls)),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    re_path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    path('api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('over',views.consol_overall_view),
]
```

while I tried to migrate and runserver it is showing an error

> path('over',views.consol_overall_view),
> AttributeError: module 'rest_framework.authtoken.views' has no attribute 'consol_overall_view'

I need the consol_overall_view in Url or as a API. If it is possible to do as API kindly guide on the same.

Answer (score 1):

When python interpreter finds imports with same name it takes the latest one into account. In your `urls.py` you have imported `views` module from two distinct packages. Python interpreter will treat the name `views` from the package `restframework.authtoken` as the `views` module not the one from `django` because the import from the first one is the latest. Apart from that, you have imported `consol_overall_view` directly from `App.views` but referring it as a value from `views` that you have imported before. Change `views.consol_overall_view` to `consol_overall_view` in your urlpatterns. Also, use aliases in your imports.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.urls import re_path
# import django.views with alias
from django import views as django_views
from App.views import CustomAuthToken
from.router import router
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from App.views import consol_overall_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="social_app/index.html")), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/',include(router.urls)),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    re_path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    re_path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    path('api-token-auth/', CustomAuthToken.as_view()),
    path('over', consol_overall_view),
]
```